# Android studio double to date format

Tags: android, excel, date

I'm making a project on android studio.
I must convert a number into an hour, minutes and seconds date.

The number is: 0,18865386
The result must be: 04:31:40

I've obtained this date whit excel (used for test calc) just changing the cell format to HOURS but i don't understand how to calculate it.

Any solutions?

Comment: Find out how it gets that number and reverse engineer it.

Answer (score 0):

1 corresponds to 24 hours.

**In hours:** 0,18865386 means `24 x 0,18865386 ~= 4,5 hours` which corresponds to your 04:31:40.

If you need more precision, e.g. **in seconds**:

The number of seconds in a day `= 24 x 60 x 60 = 86400`.
Then 0,18865386 means `86400 x 0,18865386 = 16300 seconds = 04:31:40`.